# Why does "Get-Vm | Sls PoweredOff" not grep for VMs that are Powered off?

Tags: powershell, vmware

I am trying to use PowerCLI to search for a list of PoweredOff VMs.

I want to search the results of the command `Get-Vm`:

```
Vm01 PoweredOn  1 16
Vm02 PoweredOff 1 16
etc.
```

I want to search this list for "PoweredOff", but the PowerShell `Sls` doesn't seem to work if I type:

```
Get-Vm | sls PoweredOff
```

It will not show the PoweredOff virtual machines. Can anyone provide any guidance on outputting this a stream of text to search (rather then a list of Objects to search)?

Comment: get-vm | ? state -eq Off, or some variation of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell cmdlets return objects, not simple text output. You filter output by the values of specific properties with the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-3.0) cmdlet.

```
Get-Vm | Where-Object { $_.PowerState -eq 'PoweredOff' }
```

Tabular or list output will normally show you the property names. However, not all of the objects' properties may be displayed by default, and sometimes the default output format of a particular type is made to look differently than the output would normally do (e.g. `Get-Process` output). You can get a list of all properties (and methods) of an object by using the [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Member?view=powershell-3.0) cmdlet. Add the parameter `-Force` to include intrinsic properties. Add the parameter `-Static` to show class methods instead of object methods.

For VMware's cmdlets you could also check the [PowerCLI documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI651/html/Get-VM.html), which lists the return types of the cmdlets.

Comment: Thank you so much! For my reference, in the future what is the reccomended way to convert output to "text" format and then grep it?

Comment: To not to. If you're using PowerShell: do things the PowerShell way. Otherwise don't use PowerShell in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! Ok so the equivelant of Grep in Powershell is: get-vm | out-string -stream | select-string PoweredOff

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough before. DON'T DO THAT. PowerShell is not a Unix shell and should neither be expected to, nor be made to behave like one.

Comment: So another question, how do I print out the names of the ovjects if they are too long. I did:

get-vm | where-object { $_.powerstate -eq 'poweredoff' }. but it made some of my vm names cut off: vm01-mydomaincont... <-- it puts 3 dots instead of showing the whole field

Comment: Make it an object so $myobj = get-vm -name blah. Then do $myobj.name, use$myobj | get-member to see the other fields.

Comment: @WubiUbuntu980Unity7Refugee Try `| Format-Table -AutoSize`, but only if you want to display the data to a user. Do not use `Format-*` cmdlets if the data are subject to further processing.